# Set a UITextField to write a maximum of 11 numbers using NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter

i’m trying to configure a **UITExtField** to only accept 11 numbers, i’m using **NSNumberFormatter** and it works just fine with using numbers, but when I try to set the maximum numbers available it doesn’t work.

Even assigning **setMaximumFractionDigits**, **setMaximumIntegerDigits** and **setMaximumSignificantDigits** it doesn’t work like it should, or Am i missing something? please help.

here’s my code…

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

NSNumberFormatter *num = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[num setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[num setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
[num setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
[num setMaximumIntegerDigits:11];
[num setMaximumSignificantDigits:11];

NSString *aString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]; 
//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", textField.text, string];
NSNumber *number = [num numberFromString:aString];

if (number) {
    return YES;
else
    return NO;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I reordered the code like Ian said and made the changes that Ink said too and still the same, i can write numbers only but i can write more than 11 numbers.

**EDIT 2**

Thanks Ian and Ink, now it works, I needed to check that **aString.length** were minor than 12 and it were a **number**.

```
    if (aString.length < 12 && number)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Provide some examples if what isn't working.

Comment: I really suggest not doing this. Rejecting user content changes as they type based on filtering is pretty frustrating. Text could go through a number of intermediary stages as the user enters it, and by validating as they're entering you require them to follow a path that might not be obvious to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `number` before setting your constraints on `num`... Try this instead:

```
[num setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
[num setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
[num setMaximumIntegerDigits:11];
[num setMaximumSignificantDigits:11];

NSNumber *number = [num numberFromString:aString];

if (number) {
  return [[num stringFromNumber:number] length] <= 11 && [[num stringFromNumber:number] length] == [aString length];
} else {
  return NO;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and i still can write more than 11 numbers.

Comment: Well that's because you're not checking the length of the thing, you're just using its result. It will still parse a number, it just won't necessarily match your input. If you're worried about the result, you should be comparing `aString.length <= 11` or use your number formatter to go in reverse and check that length...

Comment: What a dumb i am, i was just evaluating number itself, i needed to check if aString had a length < 12. now it works!, thanks mate for helping me realizing this!

Answer (score 1):

`aString` should be `[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]`

```
return aString.length <= 11;
```

From there you could just check the length of the string, assuming you know that it's a numeric string.  If you can't assume that, then do what @Ian MacDonald suggested and reorder your code to look like this:

```
NSNumber *rawNumber = [num numberFromString:aString];

[num setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
[num setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
[num setMaximumIntegerDigits:11];
[num setMaximumSignificantDigits:11];

NSNumber *number = [num numberFromString:aString];
return rawNumber == number;
```

Also notice that just seeing if the number formatter gave you a number isn't good enough.  You need to check and see if the number got trimmed by the formatter.

Comment: While true, this isn't an answer to the question. Make this a comment or update your answer to actually answer the question.

Comment: I did what you told me and i still get the same result; I can write more than 11 numbers.

Comment: @xzrudy added more details